# Is it possible to have a std::list as a member of a structure in C++?

Tags: c++, structure, member, stdlist

I'll describe my question using an example. I have the structure Triangle:

```
struct Triangle {
int perimeter;
double area;
list <mystruct> sides;
};
```

where mystruct is:

```
struct mystruct {
int length;
}
```

Is it possible? Are there any problems that may appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. In fact it's a [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition). You can use it like this:

```
mystruct s;
s.length = 10;

Triangle t;
t.sides.push_back(s);
```

> object composition is a way to combine simple objects or data types
>   into more complex ones.

Answer (score 0):

No problem at all.

`std::list<>` is well written/implemented and is copyable (even moveable), default constructible, and so on, so you can use it in a `struct` without fearing anything.

Answer (score 0):

The only significant difference between `struct` and `class`  for nearly all purposes is the default access specifier.